# Magento 2.3 upgrade table not found

Tags: magento, magento-2.3

Hello I just upgraded a project from magento 2.2.6 to 2.3 and i have this issue when doing **setup:upgrade**

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'catalog_category_product_index_store1_store1' doesn't exist, query
>   was: INSERT INTO `catalog_category_product_index_store1_store1`
>   (`category_id`, `product_id`, `position`, `is_parent`, `store_id`,
>   `visibility`) SELECT `catalog_category_product_index_store1`.* FROM
>   `catalog_category_product_index_store1` WHERE (store_id = '1') ON
>   DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `category_id` = VALUES(`category_id`),
>   `product_id` = VALUES(`product_id`), `position` = VALUES(`position`),
>   `is_parent` = VALUES(`is_parent`), `store_id` = VALUES(`store_id`),
>   `visibility` = VALUES(`visibility`)

Answer (score 3):

I found the root cause:

There's a plugin (Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\Plugin\TableResolver) which is adding the _store1 suffix to the $setup->getTable() call. That works great for the main app, but $setup->getTable() is also used during the data migration which runs when the _storeX tables are first created and we need the original table name to run that migration.

I solved the issue by overriding the migration data patch:
Magento\Catalog\Setup\Patch\Data\EnableSegmentation.php

Do the following:

1. Either create a new module for this override or use an existing module. There are many walkthroughs to creating a module available online.
2. Copy Magento\Catalog\Setup\Patch\Data\EnableSegmentation.php to the same path in your module. So if your module was in app\code\Company\PatchFix, you'd copy the file to app\code\Company\PatchFix\Setup\Patch\Data\EnableSegmentation.php.
3. In the copied file, update the namespace in line 7:

```
namespace Company\PatchFix\Setup\Patch\Data;
```

4. Add the following code right after the $setup object is defined (around line 58):

```
        // Get the index table name once
        $catalogCategoryProductIndexTableName = $setup->getTable('catalog_category_product_index');
        // This table name will probably not end with _index, but we need it to for this patch to work
        if (substr($catalogCategoryProductIndexTableName, -5) !== 'index') {
            while (substr($catalogCategoryProductIndexTableName, -5) !== 'index') {
                $catalogCategoryProductIndexTableName = substr($catalogCategoryProductIndexTableName, 0,
                    strlen($catalogCategoryProductIndexTableName) - 1);
            }
        }
```

It just removes the end characters from the table name one at a time until it ends with `index`.

5. Replace all of the later calls to `$setup->getTable('catalog_category_product_index')` with `$catalogCategoryProductIndexTablename`.
6. Save your changes.
7. If your module does not have an `etc/di.xml` file, either create one from scratch or copy one from another module. Again, there are guides available online to show you how to do this.
8. Add an override preference to your new data patch:

```
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Setup\Patch\Data\EnableSegmentation" type="Company\PatchFix\Setup\Patch\Data\EnableSegmentation" />
```

9. Save etc/di.xml.
10. Run `setup:upgrade`.